# Hibernate SpatialRestrictions & PostGIS alias: 'column does not exist'

Tags: hibernate, postgis, hibernate-spatial

When I specify a Criterion from `SpatialRestrictions` (e.g. `SpatialRestrictions.intersects(propertyName, geometryObj)`) the generated SQL is invalid as the column name has been aliased and used incorrectly:

Generated SQL

`SELECT this_.GEO_LOCATION as y10_ 
   FROM schema.GEO this_ 
  WHERE ( ST_intersects(y10_, 'SRID=4326;POLYGON(...)') 
     OR ST_intersects(y10_, 'SRID=4326;POLYGON(...)'))`

Is there a way to force the projection alias to be ignored and just use `table_alias.column`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing `"this." + propertyName` to the `SpatialRestriction`.